# RMySQL installing error on Fedora 28, Rstudio version 1.1.4,

Tags: r, compiler-errors, boolean, rmysql

Whenever I try to install RmySQL on Rstudio it gives me this "compiler" error tho I've installed all the requires dependencies.

```
> install.packages("RMySQL", dependencies=TRUE)
    Installing package into ‘/home/nizar/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
    (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
    also installing the dependency ‘curl’

    trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/curl_3.2.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 367047 bytes (358 KB)
    ==================================================
    downloaded 358 KB

    trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RMySQL_0.10.14.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 52703 bytes (51 KB)
    ==================================================
    downloaded 51 KB

    * installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
    ** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    Package 'libcurl', required by 'virtual:world', not found
    Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    Package 'libcurl', required by 'virtual:world', not found
    Using PKG_CFLAGS=
    Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
    ------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
    Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
     * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
     * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
     * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
    If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
    PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
    is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
    R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
    * removing ‘/home/nizar/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/curl’
    Warning in install.packages :
      installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
    * installing *source* package ‘RMySQL’ ...
    ** package ‘RMySQL’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    Found mysql_config cflags and libs!
    Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/mysql -m64 
    Using PKG_LIBS=-L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lm -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -ldl
    ** libs
    rm -f RMySQL.so RMySQL-init.o connection.o db-apply.o driver.o exception.o fields.o result.o utils.o
    gcc -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/mysql -m64   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -mcet -fcf-protection  -c RMySQL-init.c -o RMySQL-init.o
    gcc -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/mysql -m64   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -mcet -fcf-protection  -c connection.c -o connection.o
    connection.c: In function ‘RS_MySQL_moreResultSets’:
    connection.c:224:3: error: unknown type name ‘my_bool’; did you mean ‘bool’?
       my_bool           tmp;
       ^~~~~~~
       bool
    make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:159: connection.o] Error 1
    ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RMySQL’
    * removing ‘/home/nizar/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/RMySQL’
    Warning in install.packages :
      installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status

    The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpF8mtsU/downloaded_packages’
```

**I've tried to remove Mysql from fedora by dnf commands but still the same, tried "dnf install c-cran-rmysql" but it doesn't give me results ..**

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is after this line:

```
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
```

Install the `libcurl-devel` package which will also install `libcurl` if it isn't already.

`dnf install libcurl-devel`

Failing that, you can install the `RMariaDB` package instead which is more up to date as `RMySQL` is based on code which is being phased out.